# How to dispatch redux action outside of a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm using `redux` in my `react-native` mobile app.
The communication with the backend is via websockets using `socket.io`.

I organize the project in a way where I have a file (you could call it an object) which initialize the socket client.
The handlers are registered to it, and I want to send actions to the `reducers`.

`socket.js`:

```
export function createSocket (url) {
  console.log(`connecting to ${url}`)
  // dispatch(actions.CONNECT)
  return io(url)
}
```

How can I `dispatch` actions from those functions outside of any `react component`?

Comment: Lookup redux-thunk: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

Comment: My project is already integrated with `redux-saga`. Is there a way to do it with it?

Comment: Yes, both can work at the same time, although you could get the same result using a saga instead of a thunk in this case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you initialise the socket client at startup time, just pass your redux store into the function and then use `store.dispatch()`

```
export function createSocket (url, store) {
  console.log(`connecting to ${url}`)
  store.dispatch(actions.CONNECT)
  return io(url)
}
```

If not at startup, then your socket creation should be triggered by some user action (or something similar) in which case you should be able to get a reference to the dispatch function using the `redux-thunk` middleware:

```
//the action returns a function, which gets called with store.dispatch as an argument
const myAction = someArg => dispatch => {
    createSocket(url, dispatch);
};
```

See https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk for details

Comment: In m case, using umi - redux - react, store does not have dispatch function. even after initialized. Do you know why I can not access dispatch?

Comment: @efirat `app._store.dispatch` is available in umi-dva-react.

Comment: https://v2.umijs.org/guide/with-dva.html#how-to-access-store-or-dispatch
It Says

`window.g_app._store`

window.g_app._store.dispatch